# Can't connect to Samba share through OpenVPN on public network

Tags: windows, networking, openvpn, samba

I have a Windows 10 laptop that I bring around and sometimes I'll need access to my files at home. For this, I set up an OpenVPN Server and usually go through that to access my shares.

I'm using the built-in "Map network drive" function to attempt to access the servers at 192.168.1.100 and 192.168.1.200.

I can access both of these IPs through the built in SSH function, but when I try to connect to the network drives, Windows just tells me the network path was not found.

I can access both of these shares through my phone, connected to the same OpenVPN server with the same configuration (different .ovpn file).

Both the samba servers can be accessed directly on the home network through the same IP.

I'm attempting to connect through a school network.

Why is this happening and how would I go about solving it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by marking the school network as a private network. Forgot that I had file sharing disabled on public networks.

Comment: Same issue here. Is it reasonable to set an (in my case: untrusted, public) school network to private, just to use CIFS inside the OpenVPN tunnel? Is there another solution?

Comment: I didn't find any other solution, but I usually keep OpenVPN on the entire time at school, so it's not a huge problem